# AppleScript throwing errors on curly braces in string

Tags: shell, applescript, curly-braces

I'm trying to generate a shell script in AppleScript.  When using the following pattern:

```AppleScript
set tDur to "PT1H21M7S"
set tSh to "echo '" & tDur & "' | egrep -o '[0-9]+M' | sed s/M// | sed -e :a -e s/^.\{1,1\}$/0&/;ta"
```

...I get the error:

`Expected “"” but found unknown token.`

The cursor is landing on the first curly braces after the error is thrown, and I can escape the curly braces again, e.g.:

`\\{1,1\\}`

... but both escape characters end up in my shell script, which is bad.

If I remove the final sed statement:

```AppleScript
set tSh to "echo '" & tDur & "' | egrep -o '[0-9]+H' | sed s/H//"
```

... AppleScript will accept the string.  I've tried various configurations of AppleScript's `quoted form of` property (per Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-SECTION3)), but to no avail.

edit: working shell command I'm trying to get AppleScript to generate:

```
echo 'PT1H2M21S' | egrep -o '[0-9]+M' | sed s/M// | sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,1\}$/0&/;ta'
```

edit: also added the setting of the `tDur` variable for clarity.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Thanks to @foo for helping me find a working solution: `set tDur to "PT1H2M21S"` `do shell script "echo " & (quoted form of tDur) & " | egrep -o '[0-9]+M' | sed s/M// | sed -e :a -e 's/^.\\{1,1\\}$/0&/;ta'"`.  I understand the `quoted form` usage a bit better as a result.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set tSh to "echo " & (quoted form of tDur) & " | egrep -o '[0-9]+H' | sed s/H//"
```

If you're on 10.10, consider using `NSTask` via the AppleScriptObjC bridge. Unlike `do shell script`, it allows you to pass data via `STDIN`, which is the right way to do these things. (Though frankly none of this crap would be necessary in the first place if AppleScript had a standard library worth a damn.)

Comment: The line you amended was working without modification.  The first line of code in my question is the one that fails.  I just tried the form you suggested with my first code snippet, and it also fails: `set tSh to "echo '" & (quoted form of tDur) & "' | egrep -o '[0-9]+H' | sed s/H// | sed -e :a -e s/^.\{1,1\}$/0&/;ta"`

Comment: The line was wrong: `... '"&tDur&"'...` is a totally unsafe way to construct shell scripts. Your amended snippet also escapes the input wrongly: it should be `"echo " & (quoted form of tDur) & " | ...`, without the added single (`'`) quotes.

Comment: As to the backslash escapes, you had it right when you wrote `\\{1,1\\}` because AppleScript syntax rules require you to backslash-escape any double-quote and backslash characters within its string literals, otherwise the AS code won't compile.

Comment: Beyond that, if your script is still not working, it's because the shell code is wrong, but since you don't provide a runnable demonstration with appropriate sample data that's not easy for us to test. Since AS, sh, and sed all use backslashes to escape, the simplest way to reduce the number of places bugs may hide would be to put single quotes around all your arguments (`sed -e ':a' -e 's/.../;ta'`). That'll ensure any backslashes you do put within those arguments are interpreted by `sed`, not by the shell itself.

Comment: `set tSh to "echo " & (quoted form of tDur) & " | egrep -o '[0-9]+H' | sed s/H// | sed -e :a -e s/^.\{1,1\}$/0&/;ta"` where `tDur` is set to `abc123` doesn't compile for me in AppleScript.  Does it for you?

Comment: `\\{1,1\\}` is accepted by AppleScript, but rejected by the shell because all of the slashes make it through to the shell.  I want to end up with `\{1,1\}` in the shell.

Comment: working shell code sample: `echo 'PT2M21S' | egrep -o '[0-9]+M' | sed s/M// | sed -e :a -e 's/^.\{1,1\}$/0&/;ta'`

Comment: You should also test and troubleshoot your shell script in Terminal. Once it's working correctly there, paste it into your AppleScript, remembering to backslash-escape any double-quote and backslash characters when you do. Developing and assembling the code incrementally, testing at each step, is a lot easier than trying to debug the complete script where you've got three nested interpreters and consequently three levels of escaping to get just right.

Comment: OK, so convert that working shell script to a valid AppleScript string now: `do shell script "echo 'PT2M21S' | egrep -o '[0-9]+M' | sed s/M// | sed -e :a -e 's/^.\\{1,1\\}$/0&/;ta'"` and test again in SE. Once that step's working right, parameterize the hardcoded test data: `set tDur to "PT2M21S"`, `do shell script "echo " & (quoted form of tDur) & " | egrep -o '[0-9]+M' | sed s/M// | sed -e :a -e 's/^.\\{1,1\\}$/0&/;ta'"`, and test again. I'm sure you can take it from there.